# Can someone explain this weird font behavior? (EBGaramond-Maths)

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages

I am using the package `EBGaramond-Maths`.

This font is missing the symbols for these commands (from documentation):

```
\leftharpoonup \triangleright \flat \smile
\leftharpoondown \triangleleft \natural \frown
\rightharpoonup \star \sharp \vec
\rightharpoondown \partial \t
```

The default way of loading this package (as per the documentation) is

```
 \usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
 \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
```

When the above-mentioned missing symbols are used, the package prints nothing out at the command, which is to be expected. However, if we use only `newtxmath` without the `ebgaramond-maths` package, the symbols are correctly produced. Thus, we can surmise that `newtxmath` has those symbols, but  `ebgaramond-maths` does not.

However, this would suggest that when `ebgaramond-maths` is loaded, the compiler essentially "blanks out" the positions in the character map that the `ebgaramond-maths` lacks, rather than falling back on a previously loaded symbol. For example, although the `\partial` symbol is loaded by the `newtxmath` package and displays correctly when it is used without `ebgaramond-maths`, after loading `ebgaramond-maths` thereafter, the command does nothing.

1) Why does this happen?

2) If `ebgaramond-maths` just cancels whatever `newtxmath` does, then what is the point of loading `newtxmath` before?

Comment: See edited answer for an example of how to redefine missing symbols using one of the options `newtxmaths` offers for the `letters` font. (I can't ping you from my answer as you deleted your comment there.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SE!

The key issue is that `ebgaramond-maths` issues the following

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{letters}   {OML}   {EBGaramond-Maths} {m} {it}
```

This overwrites the existing `letters` font. This enables all of the characters which the font does provide and which are used in the `OML` encoding. However, it does this by telling LaTeX that whenever a maths symbol uses the `letters` font, it should use `OML/EBGaramond-Maths/m/it`. So LaTeX does this whether the symbol exists in the font or not. It cannot tell, essentially, one way or another.

To make this a bit clearer, it is helpful to look at the definition of `\partial` from `fontmath.ltx`:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathord}{letters}{"40}
```

This tells LaTeX that `\partial` corresponds to the character in the relevant slot in the `letters` font. So before `ebgaramond-maths` is loaded, this symbol will be taken from whichever font is currently configured to provide `letters` (Computer Modern by default or whatever `newtxmath` is configured to use). After `ebgaramond-maths` is loaded, the symbol will be taken from whichever font is currently configured to provide `letters`. But now that font is EBGaramond-Maths which, as we know does not provide the symbol. What it provides is an empty slot - a blank.

The point of loading `newtxmath` is for the symbols it provides in *other* encodings (i.e. not `OML`) because these complement EBGaramond better than the defaults. Hence, `ebgaramond-maths` does not 'cancel out' what `newtxmath` does. Rather, it overrides one *part* of what `newtxmath` does.

In fact, `ebgaramond-maths` knocks out symbols from the default fonts, too. (You can still reproduce the problem if you comment out the line loading `newtxmath`.)

So the sequence is as follows:

1. Default maths fonts are set up by LaTeX. (In particular, `letters` is defined.)
2. `newtxmath` is loaded and overwrites large parts of the default configuration for maths fonts. (In particular, `letters` is redefined.)
3. `ebgaramond-maths` is loaded and overwrites a part of the previous configuration for maths fonts. (In particular, `letters` is redefined.)

There are alternative approaches but I think that this is the most practical and least incompatible one. Please see [the question I asked about this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/214512/) and [David Carlisle's response](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214524/) for the background to my decision.

[I am the package author.]

## Redefining missing symbols

***Note that you must do this in the PREAMBLE but AFTER loading `ebgaramond-maths`!***

If you try to use one of the missing symbols, the package now issues an error. If you ask for help, it tells you how to define the missing symbols using the `\re@DeclareMathSymbol` command from `newtxmath`.

Here is an example of how to do this using one of the options for `letters` from `newtxmath`. Here, a new maths font, `ntxletters` is set up and missing symbols are defined using it. `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is required as the redeclaration command includes the `@` symbol.

```
\makeatletter
  \DeclareSymbolFont{ntxletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
  \SetSymbolFont{ntxletters}{bold}{OML}{ntxmi}{b}{it}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\leftharpoonup}{\mathrel}{ntxletters}{"28}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\leftharpoondown}{\mathrel}{ntxletters}{"29}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\rightharpoonup}{\mathrel}{ntxletters}{"2A}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\rightharpoondown}{\mathrel}{ntxletters}{"2B}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\triangleleft}{\mathbin}{ntxletters}{"2F}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\triangleright}{\mathbin}{ntxletters}{"2E}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\partial}{\mathord}{ntxletters}{"40}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\flat}{\mathord}{ntxletters}{"5B}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\natural}{\mathord}{ntxletters}{"5C}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\star}{\mathbin}{ntxletters}{"3F}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\smile}{\mathrel}{ntxletters}{"5E}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\frown}{\mathrel}{ntxletters}{"5F}
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\sharp}{\mathord}{ntxletters}{"5D}
  \re@DeclareMathAccent{\vec}{\mathord}{ntxletters}{"7E}
\makeatother
```

Comment: @Anthony You need the other instruction from the error message first i.e. `\DeclareSymbolFont{cmletters}{OML}{cmm} {m}{it}`. That defines the font which you then use to set the symbol. Yes, you can take the numbers from `newtxmaths`. But note that you need the `\re@DeclareMathSymbol...` and that there is a `"` in the final argument as well.

Comment: Thanks again, cfr. I seemed to get it to work with the following: `\DeclareSymbolFont{txletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftharpoonup}{\mathrel}{txletters}{40}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftharpoondown}{\mathrel}{txletters}{41}`, etc.. Why is the `\re@` component necessary? (Sorry about the deleted comments that might have been sent to your inbox.)

Comment: I am using the "slot" numbering given by the `newtxmath` package.

Comment: @Anthony If you use `\DeclareMathSymbol`, LaTeX will complain that the symbol is already defined. In interactive mode, this stops compilation. If you are using non-stop mode, look at the console output or log file. You can use `40` and `41`. Just don't use the `"` in that case. (These are just using different number bases to refer to the slots.)