# What is the problem when I use \partial with package garamond

Tags: ebgaramond, garamondx

Here is the source

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,mathrsfs,mathtools}
\usepackage{ebgaramond,newtxmath,ebgaramond-maths}
\begin{document}

$\partial$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that the font doesn't contain the symbol, as stated in the documentation of `ebgaramond-maths` (table 1).

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: See if this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215270/can-someone-explain-this-weird-font-behavior-ebgaramond-maths