# \hookrightarrow with ebgaramond-math

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages, ebgaramond

I'm using the font EB Garamond for a document I'm typesetting, but it seems that \hookrightarrow only renders a normal arrow. Here's the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond,newtxmath,ebgaramond-maths}
\begin{document}

Let $i: A \hookrightarrow B$ be an embedding.

\end{document}
```

It seems that the [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/fonts/ebgaramond-maths/ebgaramond-maths.pdf) does not mention that this symbol is not supported. So why doesn't it show up in the output file? Or if I misunderstood and it is indeed not supported, then how should I import a symbol from another font? I'm aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215270/can-someone-explain-this-weird-font-behavior-ebgaramond-maths) but I'm still not quite sure how to proceed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore the newtx definition. But looking at the font tables, I would say you are in for a few more surprises with ebgaramond math

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxletters}{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lhook}{\mathrel}{ntxletters}{"2C}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
Let $i: A \hookrightarrow B$ be an embedding.

\newpage
\xfonttable{OML}{EBGaramond-Maths}{m}{it}
\newpage

\xfonttable{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to figure this (better) way out when you posted (+1).  One question, why does the `\xfonttable{OML}{ntxmi}{m}{it}` (from which it seems you extracted `\lhook`)  not show the hooked arrow in the fonttable?

Comment: What do you mean by not showing up? The hook is at "2C" (44).

Comment: When I run your MWE, the hook shows up properly on page 1, but on the page 3 fonttable, I get a thing that looks like a `\circ`, truncated to look like a "c" in slot 44.

Comment: \lhook is not \hookrightarrow, and \hookrightarrow is not a single glyph, but a hook with an rightarrow.  try `\lhook \rightarrow` to see it.

Comment: Son of a gun!  I could have been looking all day!  Thank you for that retrospectively obvious clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed...with a sledgehammer!

Before loading `ebgaramond-maths`, I save all mathstyles of `\hookrightarrow` in their own `\savebox`.  Then, after loading `ebgaramond-maths`, I redefine `\hookrightarrow` to use a `\mathchoice` to decide which of the boxes to employ with a surrounding `\mathrel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\newsavebox\svhookrightarrow
\newsavebox\svscripthookrightarrow
\newsavebox\svscriptscripthookrightarrow
\savebox\svhookrightarrow{$\hookrightarrow$}
\savebox\svscripthookrightarrow{$\scriptstyle\hookrightarrow$}
\savebox\svscriptscripthookrightarrow{$\scriptscriptstyle\hookrightarrow$}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\renewcommand\hookrightarrow{\mathchoice
  {\mathrel{\usebox{\svhookrightarrow}}}
  {\mathrel{\usebox{\svhookrightarrow}}}
  {\mathrel{\usebox{\svscripthookrightarrow}}}
  {\mathrel{\usebox{\svscriptscripthookrightarrow}}}
}

\begin{document}

Let $i: A \hookrightarrow B$ be an embedding.

$\scriptstyle i: A \hookrightarrow B$

$\scriptscriptstyle i: A \hookrightarrow B$

\end{document}
```

[image]